# Sort matrix composed of data structures by row in C

Tags: c, matrix, typedef, quicksort

I'm trying to sort a matrix of data structures by row, but my code doesn't work, what is strange is that I don't get errors and the matrix doesn't change after quicksort method:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
    int id;
    int d;
}dist;
void quicksort_row_struct(dist matrixstruct[4][6], int primero, int ultimo, int row){
    int i, j, central;
    double pivote;
    central = (primero + ultimo)/2;
    pivote = matrixstruct[row][central].d;
    i=primero;
    j=ultimo;
    do{
        while(matrixstruct[row][i].d < pivote) i++;
        while(matrixstruct[row][j].d > pivote) j--;
        if(i<=j){
            double tmp;
            tmp = matrixstruct[row][i].d;
            matrixstruct[row][i].d=matrixstruct[row][j].d;
            matrixstruct[row][i].d=tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }while(i<=j);
    if(primero < j)
        quicksort_row_struct(matrixstruct, primero, j, row);
    if(i <  ultimo)
        quicksort_row_struct(matrixstruct, i, ultimo, row );
}
```

Now, this is main function:

```
int main(){
    dist matrix_Struct[4][6];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            matrix_Struct[i][j].id=j;
            matrix_Struct[i][j].d=rand()%100;
           }
        }
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            printf("\t%d -> %d", matrix_Struct[i][j].id, matrix_Struct[i][j].d);
                              }
                          }
           printf("\n");
      /*Here, I try to sort each row*/
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
              quicksort_row_struct(matrix_Struct, 0, 5, i);
              }
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("\n");
            for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
                printf("\t%d -> %d", matrix_Struct[i][j].id, matrix_Struct[i][j].d);
                                }
                             }
}
```

The idea of this quicksort in matrix rows works fine in matrix of integers. However, I needed to generalize it for matrix of structures.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Why aren't you just using `qsort()`?

Comment: Minor, but you don't need to swap elements `i` and `j` when `i == j`.

Comment: Is it intentional that you swap only the `d` members of the structures, and not the `id` members?

Comment: Do you anticipate wanting to use this sort for matrices with much longer rows?  For such short rows as you present in your example, an insertion sort almost certainly beats quick sort.

Comment: Ok @JohnBollinger, actually mi real matrix is 100 x 10, would it be better using insertion? btw, my main interest is to swap id, I need to get permutations.

Comment: if you want to swap the whole structures then you can do so naturally with use of whole-structure assignment.  `dist tmp = matrixstruct[row][i]; matrixstruct[row][i] = matrixstruct[row][j]; matrixstruct[row][j] = tmp;`.

Comment: Ultimately, you should answer performance questions by testing the alternatives.  There *is* a limiting size below which partitioning (further) is more expensive than applying a good comparison sort such as insertion sort, however.    This is why it is a common quicksort optimization to switch to insertion sort for small partitions.  The exact size where that helps varies with the problem details, but when comparisons are cheap, as yours are, my first guess at the limiting size would be somewhere in the vicinity of 30 elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, great remark, I'll consider it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the sort items being structures; it is bad swap code:

```
            tmp = matrixstruct[row][i].d;
            matrixstruct[row][i].d=matrixstruct[row][j].d;
            matrixstruct[row][i].d=tmp;
```

That last line should be

```
            matrixstruct[row][j].d=tmp;
```

It is also strange that you declare `pivote` and `tmp` as `double`s when the data themselves are `int`s, but for the range of `int` values in your example it will still work.